# Cost/benefit of interim professorship

Tags: professorship, postdocs, cv

What is the cost/benefit analysis for a Post-Doc taking a position as an interim professor?

Some costs I can think of: High teaching workload. Current projects suffer and a gap in publication record may result.

Some Benefits: Higher salary during interim position. The value of adding the position to your CV.

Comment: There may be some possibility of getting considered for the permanent job?

Comment: Note that in many cases research post-docs are paid better than visiting assistant professors.  Another reason for taking a VAP position is that it is a way to gain teaching experience.  In many cases, people take such positions because they're the only positions available.

Comment: You really should make your question more specific. These kinds of analyses can't be made seriously in the abstract. IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

The answer will depend on many individual factors. Some positive aspects are:

- The university gets to know you. I know of several interim professors who got a full professorship later on because everyone was satisfied with the person.
- You are gaining teaching experience. This is an important factor if you want to apply for a professorship.
- Related, but slightly different: You build up a teaching portfolio. If you are becoming a professor later, you are already having some material at hand.
- You are getting in contact with motivated students which you can involve in your research activities.
- Last but not least: Teaching can be fun :-).